# Update data but getting duplicate laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i want update this data but unit id, rute asal and rute tujuan cant be duplicate.. in my case, i only want update biaya pengantaran but getting message data is duplicate (even though it's the data itself). can u solve my problem? sorry for my broken english

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate(
        [
            'unit_id' => 'required',
            'rute_asal' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
            'rute_tujuan' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
            'biaya_pengantaran' => 'required|numeric',
        ],
        [
            'unit_id.required' => 'Unit tidak boleh kosong!',
            'rute_asal.required' => 'Rute asal tidak boleh kosong!',
            'rute_tujuan.required' => 'Rute tujuan tidak boleh kosong!',
            'biaya_pengantaran.required' => 'Biaya pengantaran tidak boleh kosong!',
            'rute_asal.regex' => 'Rute asal tidak valid!',
            'rute_tujuan.regex' => 'Rute tujuan tidak valid!',
            'biaya_pengantaran.numeric' => 'Biaya pengantaran harus berupa angka!'
        ]
    );

    $unit = $request->unit_id;
    $asal = $request->rute_asal;
    $tujuan = $request->rute_tujuan;
    $cek = BiayaPengantaran::where(['unit_id' => $unit, 'rute_asal' => $asal, 'rute_tujuan' =>  $tujuan])->first();

    $biaya = BiayaPengantaran::find($id);

    if (!$cek) {
        $biaya->update([
            'unit_id' => $request->unit_id,
            'rute_asal' => $request->rute_asal,
            'rute_tujuan' => $request->rute_tujuan,
            'biaya_pengantaran' => $request->biaya_pengantaran,
        ]);
        return redirect('/biaya_pengantaran')->with([
            'message' => 'Data berhasil diperbarui',
            'success' => true
        ]);
    } else {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'unit_id' => 'Biaya pengantaran untuk unit dan rute pengantaran ini sudah diinputkan!',
            'rute_asal' => 'Rute asal untuk unit dan rute pengantaran ini sudah diinputkan!',
            'rute_tujuan' => 'Rute tujuan untuk unit dan rute pengantaran ini sudah diinputkan!'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely want to use the [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique) validation rule.

Comment: @Peppermintology case closed bro. thank you for ur respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an exception in your check to the current ID

```
 $cek = BiayaPengantaran::where(['unit_id' => $unit, 'rute_asal' => $asal, 'rute_tujuan' =>  $tujuan])
    ->where('id', '!=', $id)
    ->first();
```